# TypeError when adding duration parameter to Flask_login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

When I pass the duration parameter through Flask_login I get a TypeError. Am I doing something wrong here?

I'm using the login_user() class exposed through the Flask_login package. I'm on python 2.7 and Flask-Login version 0.2.11. As The initial setup works great and I'm able to past user and the remember parameter through the login_user() class with no issue. However, the default remember cookie is set to 365 days and I want to reduce this. According to the documentation (found here: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_user) I should also be able to pass a duration parameter to set the length of the remember me cookie. However, when I pass the duration parameter I get a TypeError saying 'duration' is an unexpected keyword argument. Below is the snippet of code I using:

first I set a variable for the cooking length at the top of my views.py file:

```
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Then I go ahead and call the login_user() class and try to pass the duration parameter along with the user and remember parameters:

```
if u.active and login_user(u, remember=remember, duration=REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION):
                    u.update_activity_tracking(request.remote_addr)
```

When this class is called I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: login_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duration'
```

I'm not sure why this is not working and getting the TypeError. Am I doing something wrong? As noted, when removing duration the class works fine.

Comment: are you sure you use the latest Flash version ?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the flask_login version I'm using. I'm not using Flash.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like my version of Flask_login is not accepting the duration parameter. An update to my version solved the issue.

Comment: Flask_login 0.5.0 version fixed the issue for me